# s3.deleteObject not responding neither error or success

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I upload files to S3:my-bucket/utp with a presignedUrl.
When the object is created s3 triggers an event and my lambda function is called.

I then call getObject so I can hash the contents to make sure that this new upload is not a copy of a file already in my-bucket.  If it is a copy I delete it.  At least thats what I want to do.

Here is my delete code:

```
// If the utp file is already in the system we need to delete it.
async function deleteUTPFile(srcBucket, srcKey, callback){
  
  try {const params = {Bucket: srcBucket,Key: srcKey};
    console.log("DeleteObject params "+JSON.stringify(params));

    await s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log("DeleteObject Error "+err);
        return callback(err);
      }else{
        console.log("Successful delete "+ JSON.stringify(data));
        return callback(null, data);
      }
    }).promise();
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("Caught error "+ error.message);
      return callback(error);
  } 
}
```

My first attempt did not have the await/promise but it didn't work that way so I tried it this way.

As you can see I have a console.log before I make the call and after in the error block and the success block.  But when I look at the logs all I see is the before log and then the whole lambda ends:

```
2020-06-23 INFO doesObjectAlreadyExist true
2020-06-23 INFO DeleteObject params {"Bucket":"<my-bucket>","Key":"utp/Ego_is_the_Enemy.pdf"}
END RequestId: 5401b756-0869-4400-8dc0-7d3b0f02b681
```

Shouldn't I at least get some error message somewhere?  earlier in the lambda I have already done an s3.getObject and an s3.headObject so I know that I can reach s3.

Versioning is disabled.

My account has permissions

[image]

I know s3 has eventual consistency.  It has been at least 2 hours.  Probably 3.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Is there a way that I can at least get more information about what is happening?

Comment: The eventual consistency for updates/deletes should take at most a couple of seconds, so it isn't that. I wonder if you have permissions to write and read objects, but not delete. Can you try the Policy Simulator, with the role that the lambda function is using, to see if it reports any permission problem? https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can do a getObject and a headObject sdk call without your secretAccessKey but you can not do a deleteObject.

One would think that could be handled with a simple error message but it seems that is not the case.  We keep our credentials in secret manager.  I added this method:

```
async function setConfig(){
  await secrets.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, secretValue){
    if (err) {
            throw err;
      } else {
        // success getting SecretValue
          if ('SecretString' in secretValue) {
              secret = JSON.parse(secretValue.SecretString);
          } else {
              let buff = new Buffer(secretValue.SecretBinary, 'base64');
              secret = JSON.parse(buff.toString('ascii'));
          }
          AWS.config.update({accessKeyId : secret.accessKeyID, secretAccessKey  : secret.secretAccessKey});
      }  
  });
}
```

Now things are working as they should. :-)

```
2020-06-23 INFO ObjectKey utp/Ego_is_the_Enemy.pdf
2020-06-23 INFO Successful delete {}
2020-06-23 INFO Success deleteing UTP file
```